# Ionic 2 calendar / ion-card compressing on screen size change

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

How I want it to look all the time.

[image]

What happens if the display gets too small.

[image]

HTML

```
<ion-card class="has-card-footer" *ngIf="collapseCard">

  <ion-card-header tappable *ngIf="collapseCard" (click)="collapseCard = !collapseCard">
    <ion-title text-center>

      {{ viewTitle }}
    </ion-title>

  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content *ngIf="collapseCard">

    <ion-row>
      <!-- Move back one screen of the slides -->
      <ion-col size="6" text-left>
        <ion-button fill="clear" (click)="back()">
          <ion-icon name="arrow-back" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
      </ion-col>

      <!-- Move forward one screen of the slides -->
      <ion-col size="6" text-right>
        <ion-button fill="clear" (click)="next()">
          <ion-icon name="arrow-forward" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>


<calendar  
  [eventSource]="eventSource" 
  [calendarMode]="calendar.mode" 
  [currentDate]="calendar.currentDate"
  (onEventSelected)="onEventSelected($event)"
  (onTitleChanged)="onViewTitleChanged($event)"
  (onTimeSelected)="onTimeSelected($event)" 
  startHour="6"
  endHour="20"
  step="30"
  startingDayWeek="1">
</calendar>
</ion-card-content>
<button ion-button class="card-footer" *ngIf="collapseCard" (click)="collapseCard = 
!collapseCard">
Apply
</button>
</ion-card>
```

CSS

```
.has-card-footer {
padding-bottom: 15px;
}


.card-footer {
font-size: 150%;
color:white;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 15.5% !important;
background-color:#EF3024 ;
}

ion-card {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
width: 90% !important;
margin: 0 !important;
border-radius: 40px;
background-color: white;

}
```

When the content of my ion-card gets too small everything gets smooshed together.
I don't want everything to get smooshed together if the display gets too small.
I wish to have a static size of everything inside the card that is able to still change sizes without ruining the display of the contents.

Comment: add min-width to your ion-card element. for example `<ion-card style="min-width: 400px;">`

Comment: This works. 400px is still bigger than some mobile devices.

Comment: You can adjust pixels according to your requirements.

Comment: If you adjust the pixels of this, the calendar will still look compressed as in the second picture.
I'm trying to edit the
    <calendar> </calendar>
but documentation on ionic2 calendar is scarce.

Comment: If I could adjust the font size in the calendar, this would probably fix the issue.